# How to protect private Thread without using SecurityManager

Tags: java, multithreading, security, standards

Like `ThreadPoolExecutor` class, I'm using `private` background thread in my class (`MyClass`).
However, once I `start` my thread, anyone can invoke my thread's method like this:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().enumerate(threads);
threads[**index of my thread**].run();
```

and this kind of invocation breaks structure of `MyClass`.

Of cource, I can use `SecurityManager` to avoid this,
but I can't force user of `MyClass` to run JVM with `SecurityManager` installed.
So, if I don't want to break structure of `MyClass`,
I have to write lengthy code like this:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    if(.....) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("do not invoke run() directly");
}

@Override
public void setUncaughtExceptionHandler(.....){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cannot change handler");
}

........
```

Then, my question is "Who is the person responsible?"
Can I assume that no one invokes private thread's methods?
(imperfection caused by such invokation is negligible)
or
Do I have to prepare for illegal access?
(object have to be perfect in all cases)

and more generally,
Is there (official) programming standard about this kind of problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Who is this person you are worried about?  An attacker?  Another developer using your code?  On your machine or theirs?  etc...?  And is your concern that they are getting sensitive data, or just that the code won't work as designed?

Comment: I'm sorry for undetailed question.
In this case, I am worried about another developer using my code.
There is not sensitive data in MyClass.
(main function of this class is playing sound using javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine)
My intention is to make my code perfect (work as designed in all cases)
but if possible, I want to know about other cases too.
("attacker" and "sensitive" case)

Comment: Your job, as the author of library code, is to design your API in a way that makes it easy for client developers to use the library the way you intended, and hard for them to make stupid mistakes.  But, you don't need to _force_ them to use it the way you intended.

Comment: Thank you james large.  
So do you mean  
"Accessing a background private Thread is stupid mistake (hard to occur)  
and you don't need to care about it." ?

Comment: "hard to occur" is an understatement.  That's a deliberately stupid thing to do.  _No thread_ is designed to have it's run method re-called while it is currently executing.

Comment: I understand.  
Can the same thing be said of all `Thread` methods  
like `interrupt`  
when the thread is private?

Comment: It's not about the methods that are being called.  It's about _how_ they are called.  Nobody types `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().enumerate(threads);` by accident!  That's not a stupid mistake; it's a deliberate _hack_ to use your library in a way that you didn't intend it to be used.  You don't need to worry about that (see @jtahlborn 's answer for why not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @jameslarge's comment, when you build code for others to use, you don't need to worry about "malicious" usage.  You should build your API to be easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly (through appropriate documentation and reasonable use of visibility levels like public/protected/private).  It is *not* your job, however, to worry about whether or not someone will purposely call the wrong methods at the wrong times.  If they do that, then they "void the warranty".  I'm not sure if you are new to Java or not, but regardless of what "protections" you put in, there are all manner of ways to subvert code and mess with it (using reflection, decompiling/modifying/recompiling, etc).

As a side note, the SecurityManager is not there to protect the code from the user (e.g. DRM and its ilk), but is instead designed to protect the user from the code.  Hence it is not a valid way to protect your code from being "misused" by another developer.

UPDATE

Deprecation is a more complicated question.  Think about the situation where someone has been using your code for a while.  Ideally, they should be able to upgrade to new versions and not modify their code (assuming the new version is reasonably compatible with the old version).  In this case, if a deprecated method "still works" but is no longer the "right way", you wouldn't want to start throwing exceptions in previously working code.  If, however, you've given your users lots of warning, and now this method *no longer works at all*, then yes, you want to throw an exception.  That said, if you are creating an entirely new API and happen to be exposing a class with a deprecated method that you never want your users to use, then throwing an exception in that case is also reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for very clear answer.  
I see. So my excessive perfectionism was useless.  
I have made one more mistake.  
On `@Deprecated` method, I have wrote like this:

    `@Override
    public void someDeprecatedMethod(){
        throw new *****Exception("do not invoke deprecated method");
    }`

So this was wrong too, right?

Comment: @ShuS - updated my answer to address deprecation (too long for a comment)

Comment: In all cases, malicious (not caused by upgrade to new versions)  
invocation of `@Deprecated` method is "void the warranty", right?  
Thank you very much.

Comment: @ShuS - yes, if i choose to call the wrong method, then, well, so be it, it won't work correctly.

Comment: If you are building code for others to use and they may use it in an environment with a security manager where it is privileged, then you should make sure it isn't abusable. / "j2ee" option in JNLP was intended to allow enforcement of standards whilst not giving a full "sandbox".

Comment: Thank you. Is that a "attacker" and "sensitive" case?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - i assume by "abusable", you mean that other code with lower privileges should not be able to leverage your code to to do things with higher permissions than it should have?  that's about the only "abuse" that you need to worry about when running within a SecurityManager.

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes though I'm not sure of your use of "only".

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - well, i was trying to understand what abuse you were referring to.  what else would you include?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a follow-up thought:  If you are writing a library that other programmers will use, then instead of trying to hide your threads from your client, you should be doing the opposite:  When you want to create a new thread, you should allow your client to create it for you.

Use a `ThreadFactory` instance to create new threads.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

ThreadFactory myThreadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

public void setThreadFactory(ThreadFactory clientThreadFactory) {
    myThreadFactory = clientThreadFactory;
}

void someMethodThatMakesAThread(...) {

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    };
    Thread t = myThreadFactory.newThread(r);
    t.start();
    ...
}
```

If the client chooses to call your `setThreadFactory()` method, then your code will use the client's `ThreadFactory` instance to make new threads.  That gives the client a lot of power to debug the program, log thread creation events, control thread priorities, organize threads in ThreadGroups,...  All of which makes your module more useful and more attractive to a programmer who wants to use it in a large program that has many other threads besides just yours.

On the other hand, if your client chooses not to call `setThreadFactory()` then the default `ThreadFactory` will basically just call `new Thread(r)` for you.

Comment: I have thought "If I allow client users to use their `ThreadFactory`, then the thread will be under the control of them, so if they `setDaemon(true)` , I can't close my `SourceDataLine` ....." , but now I understand that is "hack"  Thank you very much.

Comment: Just re-read this answer five years later when somebody up-voted it. Thinking about user4512098's comment: There's a fine line. When I worked on commodity software products, I tried to remind myself and other engineers that, "our main job is to prevent the phones from ringing in tech-support." Sometimes you achieve that by giving customers the features that they think they want. Sometimes you achieve it by taking away features that they could use to make stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would consider the following:
1) the thread is not meant to be re-runnable, it should be started (and run) only once.
2) in order to get your thread from `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().enumerate(threads);` you thread has to be running already.
3) Adding simple check `if (isRunning()) { throw ... }` at the start of your `run()` method should solve you problems

Comment: Thank you.
I am worried about `enumerate` is invoked outside my class.
Checking `isRunning()` is effective when I am editing my code
as assertion of "this thread is not meant to be re-runnable."

Comment: Adding stuff like this to your code is going to make a mess.  it will be hard to maintain and you will be infinitely running around adding "isRunning()" and similarly useless checks to all your methods.

Comment: @jtahlborn That is true, but it will serve the purpose in this case. I am not suggesting to use it all the time but as a solution to a particular problem I would think that it is valid

Comment: True.  however, my assertion is that the original problem is invalid, which makes this unnecessary.